# VLOOKUP/Index across another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I asked this yesterday, but I've cleared up some data this time. I have the following abridged sheet:

```
Sheet1
         H                        AP                AO
1 Transaction Description    Employee Name         Type
2 ER 12345678                    blank             blank
3 ER 13182984                    blank             blank
4 ER 18213289                    blank             blank
5 ER 13829429                    blank             blank
6 ER 89234024                    blank             blank
```

And a different abridged worksheet in the same file to reference the names against:

```
Sheet2
       E                           I
1 Employee Name              Expense Report Number    
2 Chris Rock                    12345678        
3 Hank Hill                     13182984          
4 Tom Sawyer                    18213289         
5 Elon Musk                     13829429          
6 Tupac Shakur                  89234024
```

And I was wondering how to efficiently fill in the first excel sheet's Employee Name and Type columns from the matching report number of the second sheet as such:

```
Sheet1
        H                            AP              AO
1 Transaction Description      Employee Name        Type   
2 ER 12345678                    Chris Rock           A
3 ER 13182984                    Hank Hill            A
4 ER 18213289                    Tom Sawyer           A
5 ER 13829429                    Elon Musk            A
6 ER 89234024                    Tupac Shakur         A
```

My attempt so far:

```
=VLOOKUP(MID(H2,4,8)+0,'EEM BI + mapping'!E$2:I$1000,6,0)
```

However I'm not sure if VLOOKUP will work because the result I am trying to return is to the left of the column I am trying to match. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are your Transaction Description always in the format with `@@ ########`, if not then you will need to rethink your approach.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, it will always be in that format

Comment: Then check your data, make sure there are no spaces and or other non printable characters in the data.  Use `LEN()` to count the characters and make sure they are what they should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure if VLOOKUP will work because the result I am trying to return is to the left of the column I am trying to match

You are correct, `VLOOKUP` wont work in this case and you need to use `INDEX/MATCH` instead:

```
=INDEX('EEM BI + mapping'!E:E, MATCH(MID(H2,4,8)+0,'EEM BI + mapping'!I:I,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @A.S.H! feeling a little glad that we reached the same solution, however it's returning a N/A value... Any guesses as to why that is?

Comment: Reading through Index documentation, a potential error may be that my Index array does not match my Match array length?

Comment: @codeninja if there's no match `#N/A` is returned. I am not sure why there's but it's probably because of comparing numbers to strings, so I kept the `+0` suspecting you have a good reason for it. Did you try the suggestion of Scott Craner?

Comment: @A.S.H Indeed I did, but no dice. I'll have to keep experimenting to see what exactly is going on

Comment: @codeninja in your debugging process, it might be useful to try a simple `Match` formula to see if it gets a result. For example `=MATCH(13182984,'EEM BI + mapping'!I:I,0)` and check if it gets you the correct row number?

Comment: @A.S.H Interestingly, it doesn't return the row number! However when I go into the EEM BI + mapping tab and control find the number, I can find it. Any suggestions on where to go frmo here?

Comment: Then try also `=MATCH("13182984",'EEM BI + mapping'!I:I,0)` (with double quotes). also check if you have leading or trailing spaces in the cells.

Comment: @A.S.H. onto something here! Double quotes returned the correct row number! Do i somehow need to incorporate the double quotes in my formula?

Comment: @codeninja so my guess is that some of your `Expense Report` are numbers and some are text,  That needs to be unified, to the same for the match to work properly.  If you go with text then remove the `+0` from the Match, If you go with numbers leave it in.  Also you will get `#N/A` if no match is found.

Comment: @ScottCraner you seem to be correct! Looking more closely at the data, half seem to be in numbers, the other half in text. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @codeninja `IFERROR` might help here, although it is highly recommended that you unify the format in the column `I:I`, either as number or text.

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH(VALUE(MID(H2,4,8))+0,Sheet2!I:I,0))
```

It seems to work flawlessly for me.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, but unfortunately I'm getting a N/A error.. I suspect it may be due to an index and match length mismatch?